# How can I fix error "while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0" when starting web driver on jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, gradle, webdriver, testng

Currently, I have a UI automation script (selenium) (using gradle & testng), I already attached the chrome driver (for Linux) to GitHub. Then I trigger the build event on Jenkins. But the error occurs when it comes to the step open browser.
This is an image:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrwSQ.png

Log:

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
> Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
> System info: host: 'gradle-tdz09', ip: '10.60.0.13', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.14.138+', java.version: '1.8.0_252'
> Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:202)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:188)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:79)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
> at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:181)
> at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:168)
> at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:157)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:72)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:277)
> at com.grove.core.base.DriverFactory.createDriver(DriverFactory.groovy:53)
> at com.grove.core.base.DriverFactory.initDriver(DriverFactory.groovy:64)
> at com.grove.core.base.DriverFactory.(DriverFactory.groovy:69)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedConstructor.invoke(CachedConstructor.java:72)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ConstructorSite$ConstructorSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.callConstructor(ConstructorSite.java:105)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:59)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:263)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:286)
> at com.grove.core.extension.gmail.GetMessagesListAPI.getAccessTokenFromEmail(GetMessagesListAPI.groovy:44)
> at com.grove.core.extension.gmail.GetMessagesListAPI$getAccessTokenFromEmail.call(Unknown Source)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
> at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148)
> at API.Employees.Test_EmployeeManagement.API_T1619_EmployeeActivateAndAddDetails(Test_EmployeeManagement.groovy:182)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:584)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:172)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:804)
> at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:145)
> at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
> at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
> at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:770)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:591)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:402)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:396)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:355)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:304)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1180)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1102)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1032)
> at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1000)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.runTests(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:141)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.testng.TestNGTestClassProcessor.stop(TestNGTestClassProcessor.java:90)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
> at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
> at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
> at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:413)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker$TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for [http://localhost:27034/status] to be available after 20002 ms
> at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:100)
> at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.waitUntilAvailable(DriverService.java:197)
> ... 88 more
> Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
> at com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter.callWithTimeout(SimpleTimeLimiter.java:156)
> at org.openqa.selenium.net.UrlChecker.waitUntilAvailable(UrlChecker.java:75)
> ... 89 more

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to selenium but UBUNTU.Its unable to find chrome driver. You need to install the GTK+ ia32 shared libraries under 64 bit Debian or Ubuntu Linux. This package delivers a set of pre-compiled ia32 (i386 family) shared libraries, so that third-party 32bit programs can use the GTK+ widgets on 64-bit systems that include appropriate emulation support. You may need to install and use ia32-lib package on amd64 and ia64 systems. This package contains runtime libraries for the ia32/i386 architecture, configured for use on an amd64 or ia64 Debian system running a 64-bit kernel.Please refer https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/install-libgobject-2-0-so-0-on-debian-ubuntu-linux/

Comment: Are there anyway to get through of this T_T. I tried your suggestion but I'm not able to install the lib (Tons of error out there, and I googled a lot but none of them worked)